# Toggling views of your lines in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

So I was working on my computer and suddenly, I sneezed (always how these things happen) and I bumped my keyboard. Seconds later, my paintbrush strokes look like this.

[image]

How do I revert this back? (**These are not the original lines**) I hit undo, saved and closed the application, no luck. I looked for shortcuts but I see none that would help, tried everything, and I don't even know what I did that started it all.

Any guidance welcome, because I have no idea what I did.

Answer (score 3):

You're in "Outline" view mode. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> or go to *View → Outline* or *View → Preview on CPU/GPU*.